# When changing ceiling light I connected the wires wrong now no light works but breaker wasn’t tripped!

Tags: wiring, lighting, light-fixture, ceiling

I live in a condo and changed the light fixture in my den. But I connected the wrong ones together and when I turned the power back on there was a big spark from the light fixture. I then realized my wiring mistake and corrected it but the light would no longer work. I then got a new led light fixture, wired it correctly but alas it would not light up!

There are several wall outlets in the den and they are still working fine (not sure if that is relevant)

The breaker never tripped so I am confused as to what it could be and hoping I didn’t fry some wires in the ceiling creating a larger problem. Could it be that the light switch needs replacing? I clearly do not know a lot about electrical, but I appreciate ANY insight or suggestions!!

Thanks in advance

Comment: "The breaker never tripped" - how do you know? Some breakers trip and it doesn't look like they have tripped, flip it off and flip it on then you'll know for sure that it's on. If that doesn't do it then please post a picture of the ceiling box so the electrical experts here can see what's going on and help you better.

Comment: Search your condo for any GFI outlets that have been tripped and reset them.  This is unlikely, but sometimes peopled 'daisy chain'  stuff downstream from GFI outlets.  If the GFI trips, everything downstream is dead.  Oh, and you have a working bulb in the fixture...right?

Comment: Check the switch that operates the fixture to see if the backstabs failed. They do not respond well to shorts and can often burn in the clear.